# How to partially match URLs when searching with Django Full Text Search

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a Django model representing a website, and I use the [Postgres Full Text Search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) to search the Website objects. However, if you search for only part of a website's `url`, it doesn't return matching Websites.

e.g. if a Website has a `url` of "`https://www.example.com/foo/`" and you search for "example" or "foo", then that Website isn't returned in results.

I could create a new field, that's populated on save, which contains the `url`, but with parts separated by spaces. e.g. "`www example com foo`". And then index that. But then this wouldn't work if the user searched for "example.com".

**Is there some way I can use Full Text Search to search for partial matches on the `url` field, as well as still searching `title` and `description`?**

My model:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVectorField
from django.db import models

class Website(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False, max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=False, max_length=1000)

    search_document = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=["search_document"])]

    def index_components(self):
        return (
            (self.title, "A"),
            (self.url, "B"),
            (self.description, "C"),
        )
```

Not sure this is relevant, but for completeness, there's a post save signal that updates the index, something like this [from here](https://github.com/simonw/simonwillisonblog/blob/master/blog/signals.py):

```py
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, m2m_changed
from django.db.models import Value, TextField
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
from django.db import transaction
import operator
from functools import reduce

@receiver(post_save)
def on_save(sender, **kwargs):
    transaction.on_commit(make_updater(kwargs["instance"]))

def make_updater(instance):
    components = instance.index_components()
    pk = instance.pk

    def on_commit():
        search_vectors = []
        for weight, text in list(components.items()):
            search_vectors.append(
                SearchVector(Value(text, output_field=TextField()), weight=weight)
            )
        instance.__class__.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(
            search_document=reduce(operator.add, search_vectors)
        )

    return on_commit
```

Comment: Would the user specify that they are searching for 'foo' as part of a URL, or would they merely specify 'foo' and it is supposed to find it in URLs as well in other places?

Answer (score 1):

To do that naturally you would have to define a custom parser for the FTS and make a configuration to use that custom parser.  In addition to being unreasonably difficult to do, it would also interfere with your ability to use it alongside other (non-URL) fields, which I think is what your Django code is trying to do.

With the default parser, you can use ts_debug to see that 'foo' and 'example' are not returned as stand-alone tokens:

```
 select * from ts_debug('https://www.example.com/foo/');
  alias   |  description  |        token         | dictionaries | dictionary |        lexemes
----------+---------------+----------------------+--------------+------------+------------------------
 protocol | Protocol head | https://             | {}           | (null)     | (null)
 url      | URL           | www.example.com/foo/ | {simple}     | simple     | {www.example.com/foo/}
 host     | Host          | www.example.com      | {simple}     | simple     | {www.example.com}
 url_path | URL path      | /foo/                | {simple}     | simple     | {/foo/}
```

But 'foo' is returned as the token '/foo/', so maybe some kind of custom stemming rule could be applied to this.

You could process the URL column through a function which changed all punctuation into spaces, before passing that to the to_tsvector function. But I don't know how you would interface this with Django.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I do want to be able to search both URL and other fields, without the user specifying which fields to search. I could add another field to the Django model that would populate itself with a version of the URL with punctuation replaced by spaces, and then search that.